# Parse User Logout

Tags: jquery, parse-platform

How can I log the user out when he clicks the log out button? Using the Parse API, and jquery/javascript.

```
Parse.User.logOut();
```

And it diddnt seem to do the trick?

Comment: It may help people answer your question if you say what does happen when the trick isn't done.

Comment: It appears `Parse.User.logOut();` is [exactly correct](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.User.html#.logOut). Your issue is elsewhere. Please explain more fully what's happening.